# "No such file or directory" running TypeScript on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, typescript

I seem to have broken my TypeScript installation on Ubuntu 13.10 in the process of trying to build it from sources. I've given up on that and now just want to return to a working binary installation.

I removed NodeJS with `--purge` and reinstalled via

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

and ensured that 'node' is indeed pointing to NodeJS (and not the Ubuntu package "node", which I uninstalled). Typing `node` at the command-line drops me into the NodeJS prompt so that looks fine.

Then I reinstalled `npm` and then the TypeScript binary via

```
sudo npm -g install TypeScript@0.9.1-1
```

which resulted in

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/0.9.1-1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/0.9.1-1
/usr/local/bin/tsc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
typescript@0.9.1-1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript
```

I checked that `which tsc` points to `/usr/local/bin/tsc`. The contents of this file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('./tsc.js')
```

The directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/` contains

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody rolyp    4096 Oct 24 22:55 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody rolyp    4096 Oct 24 22:55 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody rolyp  323793 Aug 21 17:17 lib.d.ts
drwxr-xr-x 16 nobody rolyp    4096 Oct 24 22:55 resources/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nobody rolyp      42 Aug 21 17:17 tsc*
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody rolyp 2565152 Aug 21 17:17 tsc.js
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody rolyp 2509628 Aug 21 17:17 typescript.js
```

Finally, if I change to the directory manually, type `node`, and then enter `require('./tsc.js')` at the NodeJS prompt, then `tsc` runs successfully.

But if I type `tsc` at the command-line, I just get the obscure message

```
`: No such file or directory`
```

Note that I'm *not* getting the error `env: node: No such file or directory`, which I struggled with when I first installed TypeScript on Ubuntu, because of the node/
NodeJS clash.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to run `tsc` from the command-line via `node`, given that I can launch it manually as described above?

Comment: Clarification: if I explicitly type `node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc` instead of `tsc` then I can launch the compiler. So my question boils down to: what do I need to do so that `tsc` alone works again?

Comment: Interesting that `which tsc` on my Ubuntu 12.04 returns `/usr/bin/tsc` and it works as expected. Typing just `tsc` and hitting Enter shows the help.

Comment: Does node work fine ?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Indeed that's how it used to work with me. I broke things by doing an `npm -g install` to try to install a new compiled version of `tsc.js`. But now I don't seem to be able to restore the old config despite reinstalling node, npm and TypeScript.

Comment: @user568109 I don't know enough about node to be sure. But I can start the node REPL and do `require(./tsc.js)` and that works fine, as long as I'm in the directory which contains `tsc.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue while creating my own nodejs command line tool. I created the tool on windows using netbeans and published it to npmjs from there. After installing it using npm on Ubuntu I tried running it but I received the same error message. I tried everything to fix it, I even reinstalled Ubuntu but nothing worked.

The solution that I found was very simple though. I created a new entry point file (the one the starts with #!/usr/bin/env node) and copied the content of the old one to it. I did that using netbeans as well but on Ubuntu this time. Probably the file encoding was different.

So in your case, just create a new tsc file in the same location (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc) after copying the old one to a different location and then copy and paste the content of the old one to the new one. Probably this should be fixed by TypeScript developers.

Comment: Excellent! That does, indeed, fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: Wow, this worked for me too after thinking it was come coding error on my part for way too many hours.

Answer (score 13):

I install node from package manager as nodejs. To solve issue : “No such file or directory” running TypeScript, I use  digitalmediums sugestion from https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3911:
just create symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: You're right that it's important not to confuse `nodejs` with `node` and that if you have both installed you will probably need some kind of link to ensure that `node` points to `nodejs`. 

However I've been through this aspect of the installation, and this isn't actually related to my problem. `node` runs fine, as mentioned above.

Comment: To achieve that nodejs is available as node it is better to install
    `$ sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`
So the above mentionend sym link is tracked by a package.
    `$ dpkg -L nodejs-legacy
    /usr/bin/node`
    `$ ls -l /usr/bin/node
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Aug 23 21:25 /usr/bin/node -> nodejs`

Answer (score 6):

sudo gedit /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc

updated the initial Content

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('./tsc.js')
```

TO

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
require('./tsc.js')
```

Comment: This is the best answer. This is an old issue and Typescript's developers have not fixed this yet. :(

Answer (score 3):

On ubuntu, install the package nodejs-legacy

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Comment: Worked for me when i get the error for typescript-node

Answer (score 1):

You can run tsc with `node` so `node tsc` instead of simply `tsc`. That should work on mac / linux / windows.

Comment: That really didn't answer his question. `tsc` alone should work.

Comment: I guess I can just set up `tsc` to be shorthand for `node [full path to tsc]`. But surely some part of the installation process should achieve this in a more standardised way.